# ASP.NET site on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I am trying to open my aspx web site on IIS and it opens perfectly the default page (default.aspx), but all the rest pages aspx (in the links, iframe) doesnt open, gives me an error:

Error HTTP 404.0 - Not Found

They all are present in the folder. I when i choose them like default page it opens them all, but when i try to open the same pages like link or like iframe doesn't work. External links opens perfectly. I dont know what is missing. All comments are very appreciated

Comment: You probably have the relative path(s) wrong. If you show the markup it will help.

Comment: i am sorry what do you mean by markup?

Comment: Put up your code please.

Comment: Here is my web.config:

Comment: `<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WebApplication1-20131018100218.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WebApplication1-20131018100218;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings> `

Comment: `<system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity" />
      </namespaces>`

Comment: `<system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
    </modules>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <clear />
                <add value="default.aspx" />                
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
  </system.webServer>`

Comment: `<runtime><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
<dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234"/></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding></runtime><entityFramework><defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework"/><providers><provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/></providers></entityFramework>`

Comment: But when i put this site on external host everything is ok. Maybe i have wrong configuration of IIS?